# does python has a way to implement C#-like indexers?

Tags: c#, python

how to implement in python c# indexers-like this[int i] {get set}? In other words, how to write the follow code in python?

```
public class foo{
    ...
    List<foo2> objfoo;
    ...
    public foo2 this[int i] {
      get{ return objfoo[i]; }}
}//end class foo

//in another class or method...
ofoo = new foo();
...
foo2 X = ofoo[3];
```

Comment: Example: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577703-item-properties/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a class work similarly to a [Python list](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (which is similar to arrays in other languages), you can subclass list and give your class custom methods and properties without overriding the any of the list methods or properties unless you need to.

Trying to mimic some of what you've posted:

```
class foo(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.extend(args)
        self.x = "Now"

    def smack(self):
        print("Smackity!")

ofoo = foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print(ofoo[3])  # Prints 4
print(ofoo.x)   # Prints "Now"
ofoo.smack()    # Prints "Smackity!"
```

You can use normal list methods to add or change the indexed items any way you want.

Also, here's [more on lists](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html), if it helps.